# How to access virtual machine in KVM without ssh?

Tags: server, virtualbox, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

How can I access virtual machine in KVM without ssh, ssh port is disabled and I want to enter the virtual machine and enable it.  I tried `virsh console` and VNC solutions  , they did  not work because it is not enabled from inside. It  seems it is impossible to enter the virtual machine. IS there any way to enter?

Comment: what you mean physically access?

Comment: Try `virt-manager` (requires a graphical X display) on the host computer. It can access "physical" consoles of the VMs (`virsh console` can access only serial consoles AFAIK, so if you haven't enabled a serial console, it will not work).

Comment: @raj can I download virt-manager, in host server? because i tried in local machine, it did not work.

Comment: @user68186 server is in the office, how can I login to guest machine? it is server not desktop. I quite don't understand what you mean by locally login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest method to access virtual machine consoles is the program called `virt-manager`. It is a GUI program that is an "all in one" solution to manage virtual machines in general - create, modify, start/stop them etc.

You may have `virt-manager` already installed on your server as a part of KVM installation. If not, install it as you usual install any software, using the command

```
sudo apt install virt-manager
```

You should run `virt-manager` with root privileges (otherwise it may have trouble communicating with `libvirtd` daemon on your machine), ie.

```
sudo -b virt-manager
```

(the `-b` parameter to `sudo` tells to run the program **in background** - as GUI programs are usually run - to avoid blocking the terminal).

The program is basically self-explanatory and you can easily access the VM console with it.

However, because it is a GUI program, the tricky part is how to get it running on a remote server that you access via SSH (I suppose so, because you didn't specify exactly how do you access the server).

Running a GUI program on a remote server requires two things:

1. an X server running on the **local machine** (from which you SSH to the server), to be able to display the GUI, and
2. configured **X forwarding** over SSH between remote and local machine.

As for 2), you need to edit the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on your server and check if it contains a line that says

```
X11Forwarding yes
```

It usually doesn't, so you have to add that line and save the modified file (note: you must do it as root, eg. use `sudo` to call your preferred editor on the file). After this, you need to restart the ssh service:

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

As for 1) the easiest case is when your local machine is also a Linux machine, as it already has a X server running to operate its local GUI :). In that case you don't need to do anything special besides adding a `-X` parameter to `ssh` command when you connect to the server:

```
ssh -X youruser@yourserver
```

The `-X` parameter tells `ssh` to forward the GUI over SSH to the local X server, so the program running on server will display its GUI on your local computer.

If your local machine is a Windows machine, then you need to install locally some software that provides the X server functionality (for example [Xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/)). After X server is started, you need to tell your SSH client to forward the GUI. The exact way how to do it depends on the SSH client you use.

If you are using the built-in `ssh` command in Windows 10/11, it should support the `-X` option similarly to the Linux one (but I haven't tested it).

If you are using PuTTY (which is probably the most popular SSH client for Windows), before opening the connection you should go to Connection -> SSH (click "+" to expand) -> X11 in the options screen, and then tick the check box "Enable X11 forwarding" - this is equivalent to specify the `-X` parameter in `ssh` command (I have tested it and can confirm it works).

Below you can see a screenshot of `virt-manager` accessing a VM console on the server (the server in this case is CentOS, the local machine is a quite old version of Ubuntu, the VM is OpenWRT :)) :

[image]

Comment: my local machine is Mac , server is ubuntu,X11Forwarding will be fine?

Comment: I haven't used a Mac, but from what I know it's basically a BSD system, so it should work similarly to Linux. After you configure X Forwarding on the server side, `ssh -X` command on the Mac should work.

Comment: thanks, i will try tomorrow in office

Comment: Thanks man, you saved me , I posted what I did differently

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentioned, the suggestion given by Raj and made the following changes to resolve the issue I was encountering:

```
I used "virt-manager" instead of "sudo -b virt-manager".

I used "sudo usermod -a -G libvirt $USER" to add user to the "libvirt" group because it was encountering a permission error.
```

The use of "virt-manager" instead of `sudo -b virt-manager` is meant to avoid using the "sudo" command, which elevates privileges and can cause issues with the display. The use of `sudo usermod -a -G libvirt $USER` adds the user to the "libvirt" group to resolve the permission error that was preventing the connection to the libvirt daemon.

Comment: One more correction: use `virt-manager &` instead of just `virt-manager` to run the program in background and avoid blocking the terminal.